# Where is ICCs handled in the Android stack?

Tags: android, android-intent, ipc

I was assigned to do a project in which I should write an app for Android to intercept all communicating Intents passing around in the framework. In fact, I would like to intercept all ICCs (inter-component communication) going on now in a device including all IPCs.

AFAIK, there are two general ways to do an ICC in Android listed below.

- Intent passing (between Activities, Services and Receivers).
- Bound Services to which Activities can bind themselves.

For getting this project done, should I manipulate Android framework to hook some specific modules? (Although I would not to do so).

I rather more interested in creating an app to intercept all ICCs *without* manipulating the framework. Is it possible at all?

If I should touch the framework, please tell me at which module(s)/component(s) all ICCs would be handled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I manipulate Android framework to hook some specific modules?

Yes. Because of process sand-boxing feature of Linux kernel, your app cannot access other apps' information or what is going on there.

> I rather more interested in creating an app to intercept all ICCs without manipulating the framework. Is it possible at all?

Absolutely No.

> If I should touch the framework, please tell me at which module(s)/component(s) all ICCs would be handled?

For intercepting all ICCs, including starting Activities, starting Services, binding to services and sending broadcasts, you could manipulate [Activity Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html) service.

Whenever in your app, you call `startActivity()` (and of all its flavors e.g. `startActivityForResult()`), `sendBroadcast()`, `startService` and `bindService` (of which both RPC and using [Messenger](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Messenger.html)), the following steps will be taken. (behind the hood !)

- Your app contact `Service Manager` through Binder mechanism presented in the Kernel.
- `Service Manager` acts like an index to registered system services. So it would return back a handle to the `Activity Manager` to your app via Binder mechanism.
- Your app now call the method specified on the `Activity Manager` instance it just got.
- In `Activity Manager` further steps will be taken, such as: Intent resolution (via `resolveIntent()` method of `Package Manager`) and also Permission checking.

**Two options for your case:**

1. Manipulate `Activity Manager` codes directly.
2. Define your own a system service that acts like a proxy for the `Activity Manager` and register it to `Service Manager`. ***`Recommended`***